# Discord.py exception statement

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a music bot with discord.py and I'm trying to use an `except:` statement to figure out if it is a valid url or not so I know to search for it or not. I'm trying to figure out what exception to put in the statement but when I try `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError(e)` there is a syntax error saying that e is not defined. I know that I can leave the space after the `except:` keyword blank but I want to try and figure it out because flake8 is highlighting it. Please help.

[Here is a picture of the syntax highlight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECTA.png)

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

    game = discord.Game("Music")
    await client.change_presence(activity=game)


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str = None):
    if url is None:
        await ctx.send("Put YouTube video's link after the \"play\" command.")
        return

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the currently playing music to end or use the @\"stop\" command.")

    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="music lounge")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is not None:
        if not voice.is_connected():
            voice = await channel.connect()
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    ydl_opts = {
        "format": "bestaudio",
        "postprocessors": [{
            "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",
            "preferredcodec": "mp3",
            "preferredquality": "192"
        }]
    }

    try:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([url])
            await ctx.send("Downloaded music...")
    except:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch: {url}", download=True)

            for url in info_dict["entries"]:
                print()

                title = info_dict.get("entries")[0].get("title")
                await ctx.send(f"Downloaded {title}")

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is not None:
        if voice.is_connected():
            await voice.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is not None:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.pause()
        else:
            await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is not None:
        if voice.is_paused():
            voice.resume()
        else:
            await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is not None:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.stop()
        else:
            await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: You don't handle `CommandInvokeError` with a try/except statement, it should be handled inside an error handler.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to python. How would I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling), it's explained pretty well.